# How do I set the Case origin to Chat from my PreChat form?

Tags: case, servicecloud, liveagent

the field Origin already exists and is a picklist with Chat as one of the options

Comment: could you add some details to where and how you're trying to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the detail as a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:caseOrigin" value="Chat" />
```

Map it:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case"   
       value="Origin,caseOrigin;" />
```

Specify that you want it created:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" 
       value="Origin,true;" />
```

If you want to show the Case when it is created make sure you set that as well:

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true" />
```

Note that if you are mapping multiple fields, the map and create inputs take a semi-colon separated list. For example, if you were mapping a caseSubject detail in addition to your caseOrigin detail, you'd have something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" 
       value="Origin,caseOrigin;Subject,caseSubject;" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" 
       value="Origin,true;Subject,true;" />
```

---

There isn't a ton of information out there on the Live Agent Pre-Chat API and Pre-Chat form, yet, as it is still relatively new.  I recently wrote [a very detailed article about the live agent pre-chat API](http://peterknolle.com/live-agent-pre-chat-api/).

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on what your code looks like (I am assuming it is a custom vf page with a class?) When saving the record you simply set the field to that value.. Here is what it would look like in one form or another..

```
Case c = new Case(Origin = 'Chat');
insert c;
```

or

```
Case c = new Case(); 
c.Origin = 'Chat';
insert c;
```

or to get a bit more detailed..

```
public Case cseObj {get; set;}

public PageReference saveCase() {
  cseObj.Origin = 'Chat';
  insert cseObj;
}
```

but again this all depends on how you are doing it, so **more information would be nice..** I am also positive you could do this with some kind of workflow etc, but this is the code way :-) or at least some of the ways to accomplish it via code.. If you are using a Standard Controller for Case it is a bit different, but not by much..

Comment: The case doesn't get created from a controller in live agent.

Comment: well at the time it wasn't clear what he wanted, so I didn't know he was talking about 'live agent'